# Order of growth listing

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I was just wondering if you guys could give me some sample order of growth listings, like the following:

```
n^n>n!>2^n>n^2>nlogn>n>n^1/2>logn>constant
```

Do you know any more and where they would fit in? Is there any easy method to find out where a new function composed of these function would fit in? (For instance what if I had `(2^n)/n`?).

Comment: There are an infinite number of possibilities here (`n^n^n`, `n^n^n^n`, `n^n!`, etc.), so as such, this is probably not a good StackOverflow question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is homework.

Comment: Check this answer here I think it might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/22813786/8422847

Answer (score 4):

[image]

This will help! , have a look at image attached above, it is growth graph of Big O Notation.