# Order the growth rate of a function

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I have come across some of the difficulties during doing this question. The question is: rank the following by growth rate:

> n, √n, log n, log(log n), log<sup>2</sup> n, (1/3)<sup>n</sup>, n!

What is the order for the above question? I would also like to know if is there any easy way to determine that (in general)?

My answer to this question is

> (1/3)<sup>n</sup> ⋞ log(log n) ⋞ log n ⋞ log<sup>2</sup> n ⋞ √n ⋞ n ⋞ n!

Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

You have to learn big O notation.

it's all about exponentiation ranking... you can have:

- 1 constant (exp n^0)
- 2 logarithmic (exp n=1/c)
- 3 linear (exp n^1)
- 4 polinomial (exp n^c)
- 5 exponential (exp c^n)
- 6 factorial (exp n!)

that's the basic rule. On the long run each one "wins" against the lower ones (e.g. rule 5 wins over 4,3,2 and 1)

Using this principle, it is easy to order the functions given from asymptotically slowest-growing to fastest-growing:

1. (1/3)^n - this is bound by a constant! O(1)
2. log(log n) - log of a log must grow slower than log of a linear function.
3. log n
4. log^2 n
5. √n  - n^(1/3), sub-linear, but faster than any log
6. n   - linear is a 1st degree polynomial
7. n!  - factorial grows faster than any exponential.

Comment: How one should prove this? When I have two functions, I can calculate the limit of their ratio. How should I go about it when I have multiple functions to compare? Proof by substituion/induction? Or is it sufficient to simply state this principle?

Comment: @Camilla you can actually prove it formally, but usually a calculator is all you need to verify which function wins over the other on the long run.

Comment: Would N^1.5 compared to N^2 have the overall same growth rate?

Comment: @SamuelP they are both polynomial so yes, same growth rate.